# is it possible to Integrate iAd and AddMob in single Application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, admob, iad

Hi my requirement like this:I required iAd and AdMob in single Application and if iAd fails to to show advertisement then AdMob should start showing advertisement and vise versa.I have tried https://www.adwhirl.com/ but i am not able to integrate in my Application Please anybody have any idea regarding this or any sample code.Please guide me on this task.

Comment: It should be hard to build this on your own. I believe adwhirl is the simple way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple and you don't have to use **adwhirl**. Just integrate the **iAd** and **AdMob** SDKs.
Then you could create a custom view that tries to load the iAd first and when no iAd is available, replace the iAd view with the AdMob view in

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```